# Map array of functions preserving parameter types. Can variadic tuple types from TypeScript v4 improve this?

Tags: typescript

Initially, I wanted to type  `redux`' `mapDispatchToProps`-like function and got stuck with handling an array of functions (action creators) as an argument. There is a hacky but working example. I wonder if it can be improved.

<strike>The problem is that return type does not preserve types per item, it gets generalized to a union.</strike>

**Update:** the problem is in preserving parameter types per function in the resulting array.

In short, code below should be with no errors:

```js
type F = (...x: any[]) => any
type Wrap<T extends F> = (...x: Parameters<T>) => void

const wrap = (fn: any) => (...a: any) => {fn(...a)}

// currently working solution
// the problem is K being too wide (number | string | symbol) for array index thus silenced
// // @ts-expect-error
// function main<Fs extends readonly F[]>(fs: Fs): {[K in keyof Fs]: Wrap<Fs[K]>}

// TODO: desired solution but not finished: every item in `fs` should be wrapped with `Wrap`
function main<Fs extends readonly F[]>(fs: Fs): [...Fs]

function main(fs: any) {return fs.map(wrap)}

const n = (x: number) => x
const s = (x: string) => x
const fs = main([n, s] as const)

// TEST PARAMETERS TYPES
fs[0](1)
fs[1]('1')
// @ts-expect-error
fs[0]('1')
// @ts-expect-error
fs[1](1)

// TEST RETURN TYPES
const _1: void = fs[0](1)
const _2: void = fs[1]('1')
// @ts-expect-error
const _3: number = fs[0](1)
// @ts-expect-error
const _4: string = fs[1]('1')
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUA6NAPAXFAhgOxAG0BdASgQD5cCAoUSKAdQCccwAeAFSgnWAjwATAM6wqiVBmwAFHKwC2Efs2FcK5eFQBuAewCWgmjQDGOvMOBQA7qzAJkAMzzZ8IDVUkocLgu6gBvJ08cUgBfIwB6CKhjAFdmZgFgABsQax1mAGs9PABzKGEdZNjgPTMaKKhgAAtoMGYdACNkiHkoPVEAaShGiBz84B0dawNoJDxY+V7mKAAfAuBmfrmCkCmi8gcM3AScNJzBXirq2NFhPRa8YwhDSsqAAWBhAFpeSGNgV4SMiuiHWKupTMUHkOBy7Bgol4-CEokSOEEZlSsBIFCQDmE2EhpGw-kI3RyUEyEBAOgcsGExGwLDYEOE+OIFHCvygnAA8gARNnYQ7nRKCApFEplPA9EpQPA6SwOHIdWqCbAQLQQZj7fhtQkAAwxmoK1R0sWSAt61lskAFVj0NSgmppYE1NH+gJFILBeDpPD4AhEUHhiLwyJgqPRmIpOKghDQKEhxCMTo+LtBORDPjcAUSwHiooxKFBYCQNjYYSMpnMllFEiwEsm0z86BMZgsBXsSCrFiWeTrDbLUAx9iTeCQhDwABoCsRcKJSxZSJFopwAKIAZW40gAggAlNcAWQXi43S9ZAE1pMvHfSAAzEJAARlnGMIN+vAHIb8-Zw8nq90O9PiqGsw56EFeSCvu+LKPC8bwQB8XwAUBT63rOLKLiuUAbnuACqG4AHLHqeS7dk2AD6N7YLoBj2A+IF3kRljEQATOR+gCogD6IWBH7RJB36-nBPzTvRADM2ATFMKpUZe160Z+UE-jBf7fIBglQMRAAs2DtssbH0hxb6zkAA)

**P.S:** there is [an open (as for 25-aug-2020) github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) related to problem of my solution #1, so it is not about variadic tuple types but about `keyof ArrayType` being too wide for an array index type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need TS4 variadic tuples at all. just mapped (tuple) types. The following works in TypeScript 3.5 (though `// @ts-expect-error` is a 3.9 feature):

```
function main<Fs extends readonly F[]>(fs: Fs):
    { [K in keyof Fs]: Fs[K] extends F ? Wrap<Fs[K]> : never }
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUA6NAPAXFAhgOxAG0BdASgQD5cCAoUSKAdQCccwAeAFSgnWAjwATAM6wqiVBmwAFHKwC2Efs2FcK5eFQBuAewCWgmjQDGOvMOBQA7qzAJkAMzzZ8IDVUkocLgu6gBvJ08cUgBfIwB6CKhjAFdmZgFgABsQax1mAGs9PABzKGEdZNjgPTMaKKhgAAtoMGYdACNkiHkoPVEAaShGiBz84B0dawNoJDxY+V7mKAAfAuBmfrmCkCmi8gcM3AScNJzBXirq2NFhPRa8YwhDSsqAAWBhAFpeSGNgV4SMiuiHWKupTMUHkOBy7Bgol4-CEokSOEEZlSsBIFCQDmE2EhpGw-kI3RyUEyEBAOgcsGExGwLDYEOE+OIFHCvygnAA8gARNnYQ7nRKCApFEplPA9EpQPA6SwOHIdWqCbAQLQQZj7fhtQkAAwxmoK1R0sWSAt61lskAFVj0NSgmppYE1NH+gJFILBeDpPD4AhEUHhiLwyJgqPRmIpOICUHx7VFxNJ5MhVIpDM9MJ9cAA-ExbHSGVRsHglSqoOEooQ0CgE0YnR8XaCciGfG4AolgPFRRiUKCwEgbGwwkZTOZLKKJFgJZNpn50CYzBYCvYkGOLEs8lOZ0OoBj7HW8EhCHgADQFYi4USDiykSLRTgAUQAytxpABBABKT4Asjfby+76yAJrSPejr0gADMQSAAIyXhihAQeBADkEHwZeDxPK86DvJ8KoNMwwGEGBSCIchLKPC8bwQB8Xw4XhcGQZeLK3g+UAvl+ACqL4AHL-oBd7rnOAD6EHYLoBj2DBBFQXxlj8QATMJ+gCogMG0URKHRKR6GYVRPzntJADM+YTkWSmgeBkmoWRGEUVh3y4bpUD8QALNgy7LCZsEIUh9GVE+HIcjeHKYFJVQQHOiCEDQUBRTEs5FBAKDJDouQHpF0WLoZUwqlOKXEAA3MFGIydubpIPwF75UAA)

---

Update: On array (rather than tuple) types, the above will return an array type where the individual indices are no longer known. Once the tuple indices are lost there is no way to recover this information. You can use `as const` to prevent the initial loss of the tuple information:

```
const test3 = [
    console.log,
    (x: number) => x,
] as const;
const fs3 = main(test3);
// const fs3: readonly [Wrap<(...data: any[]) => void>, Wrap<(x: number) => number>]
```

If you want to be sure you aren't losing the indices, it is possible to reject array types and only allow tuples using a bit of a hack:

```
function main<Fs extends readonly F[]>(
    fs: number extends Fs['length'] ? never : Fs):
    { [K in keyof Fs]: Fs[K] extends F ? Wrap<Fs[K]> : never }
```

(edit: `K in Exclude<keyof Fs, keyof []>` -> `K in keyof Fs` like above, not sure why I had that)
Like above, all of this works in TS3.

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUA6NAPAXFAhgOxAG0BdASgQD5cCAoUSKAdQCccwAeAFSgnWAjwATAM6wqiVBmwAFHKwC2Efs2FcK5eFQBuAewCWgmjQDGOvMOBQA7qzAJkAMzzZ8IDVUkocLgu6gBvJ08cUgBfIwB6CKhjAFdmZgFgABsQax1mAGs9PABzKGEdZNjgPTMaKKhgAAtoMGYdACNkiHkoPVEAaShGiBz84B0dawNoJDxY+V7mKAAfAuBmfrmCkCmi8gcM3AScNJzBXirq2NFhPRa8YwhDSsqAAWBhAFpeSGNgV4SMiuiHWKupTMUHkOBy7Bgol4-CEokSOEEZlSsBIFCQDmE2EhpGw-kI3RyUEyEBAOgcsGExGwLDYEOE+OIFHCvygnAA8gARNnYQ7nRKCApFEplPA9EpQPA6SwOHIdWqCbAQLQQZj7fhtQkAAwxmoK1R0sWSAt61lskAFVj0NSgmppYE1NH+gJFILBeDpPD4AhEUHhiLwyJgqPRmIlk2mnphPshhAA5JdcjVY8QoAB+CVKlVQLHCHEBKD49qi4mk8mQqkUhmR72iODpu10hlUbB4TMzcJRQhoFDloxOj4u0E5EM+NwBRLAeKijEoUFgJA2NhhIymcyWUUSLBhqYqvzoExmCwFexILcWJZ5PcHtdQDH2Id4JCEPAAGgKKZwolXFlI16Pz9fApKXvN0n0A4DPxiQ9gF-FlOAAUQAZW4aQAEEACVUIAWXghD0MQ1kAE1pCQx16QABmIJAAEZfwxQhqKo2NqNjX8HieV50HeT4VQaZgyMISikGY1iWUeF43ggD4vj4gTGJo2DKgQ5CoHQ3CAFV0IAOSIkjEL-SwAH1qOwXQDHseihNogyoEMgAmUz9AFRB6PkkS2OicTOO4mSfm-IyAGYW3DLMXIoqjrPYiSuKknjvn4-zbIAFmwc9ljChimJYxTolQjkOXgjlMBs-gj0QQgaCgKqoPMIoIBQZIdFyF9Kuq09gp3Zg9xa4gAG4xI4yTpN4vzoNvYQ7JA4dSpg-qVzGmaAvsCrqpqwoWgapqWtW9rt2mbqaA-L9oP6xKMSWxAHyQRbSDmlk2UyN89HJUlYl9CAcGSZErHwSxBh6eFMnaSxXoWC5khifBuxZRpxRqDp0jwWNLGqNhIFFRo0hwYxjFGPBgBQEqIAsFL3oRJE0iQTxBBwYBvGoIgyEoKAzMEUgSCgAAyfMExqbBJtCZbWqq786s25rheQLcJk6g6jrW4A5rO4Qkqmx8ZqS26WWV0n-HCIA)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it is not the case since even in your added example type of `fs2` is `const fs2: Wrap<(...data: any[]) => void>[]`, i.e. types are broken

Comment: `@ts-expect-error` is here to annotate expected error, and if there is no error in the line below then this comment itself becomes an error. So, you still have to check it on TS@3.9+

Comment: Are you saying you want to only allow input that can have the tuple type inferred and create an error if only a list type can be inferred?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass in a list of functions A and get back a list of wrapped functions B each with exact same parameter types as in A. Not widened union type which is TS's default type inference behavior.

Comment: Of course once the type is widened there is no way to recover the tuple indices. But there is a way to just reject non-tuple array input: I updated the answer with it

Comment: preventing from passing non-const array is quite handy from the user's perspective, as far as there are no simpler ways to achieve this your updated type definition seems to be the best option

Comment: apparently this breaks another use case: declaration via array destructuring https://tsplay.dev/vwjQkW

Comment: Seems like the `Exclude<keyof Fs, keyof []>` was removing the @@iterator, removed: https://tsplay.dev/1WGRVm

Comment: Now it works, thanks. I tried to keep 'length' property in order to allow destructuring and it didn't work. So my question is where can I read about @@iterator?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript 4.0 can indeed represent [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) so you can annotate your `main` function to indicate what it does; maybe something like this:

```
const main = <F extends any[]>(f: F): [...F] => [...f];
```

(If you want to make it `F extends Function[]` or some specific subtype of function that should work too, but for this example I'm just using `any` instead of a function type.)  Now your example above behaves as you want:

```
const n = (x: number) => x
const s = (x: string) => x
const [n2, s2] = main([n, s])
n2(1) // okay
s2('1') // okay
n2('1') // error
s2(1) // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJZhgXhgHgGIwKYAeUeYAJhDAmAJ4DaAugHwAUAZgFwzYCUntAdIOz10jGAMGt6AbgBQoSLFQZmBTmACucAEZ4ATt1EwC88NBgUVai1D0oA5obRiCMU4vFgATABoLXkQxEFGZaMD8Iem5Zb2YARkMAekSYEABrBGpZCC9mAHI4vKSU9MyY3IKimGT8PT0QPWzchOqU-Xq9IA).

But you could get something like this behavior for TypeScript 3.9 and below by [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the return type is the same as the input type, which is close enough to what you're doing and behaves the same (the difference between `[...F]` and `F` is small enough not to worry about in most cases):

```
const main = <F extends any[]>(f: F) => [...f] as F;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJZhgXhgHgGIwKYAeUeYAJhDAmAJ4DaAugHwAUAZgFwzYCU6jMtAHTDW9ShWwBuAFChIsVBmYFOYAK5wARngBOvNPwKzw0GBSUqzUHSgDm+w8fkCwAJgA0Z12IyIUzWjBPCHpuGTdmAEZeAHoYmBAAawRqaQhXZgBySMzY+KSU6Qjs3Jg4-B0dEB00jOiy+N0qnSA)

---

Note that sometimes the compiler doesn't infer tuple types where you want it to without hints; by writing `const [n2, s2] = main([n, s]);` you're hinting that you want tuples, so you get tuples.

Otherwise, `const n2s2 = main([n, s])` would just be a unordered array type whose elements are of a union type.  You could give a hint in the type signature of `main` by making the `F` type parameter include a tuple type in its constraint:

```
const main = <F extends any[] | []>(f: F) => [...f] as F;
```

(see [microsoft/TypeScript#27179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179) for this idea) which makes this work:

```
const n2s2 = main([n, s]);
// const n2s2: [(x: number) => number, (x: string) => string]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJZhgXhgHgGIwKYAeUeYAJhDAmAJ4DaAujAD4wMB8AFAGYBcM2ASnRtWAOnFdGCCtgDcAKFCRYqDBwJ8wAVzgAjPACchaEQUXhoMCmo1WoBlAHNjp88phgATBE-p4yMA5aMAAaK3oBBQB6KJglSy8fPlp1TR19I2EPdMMw1LsHMGcs6ELHejcE3wxEz1oABnoFeNgfP1raAEYm+S8OTqEYmBAAawRqeR8OAHJO6cHY0fHezxm5hfwDAxADSdWBmCHDbYMYIA)

---

So, some combination of those techniques should hopefully overcome the problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, but I updated my question with little more details: there is also a mapper function

Comment: Also, I was unaware of the difference of tuple declaration - seems like a middle way between `const n2s2 = main([n, s])` and `const n2s2 = main([n, s] as const)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to let typescript infer the tuple type. Reading up on [Variadric Tuples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types), it looks you need to constrain the generic type parameter to type `any[]` and then return a spread of that generic parameter:

```
type Main = <T extends any[]>(fns: T) => [...T]

const main: Main = (fns) => [...fns]
```

Now the rest works just like you expect.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwHZQLxQDwBUoQB7ARIAmAzlHEiANoC6AfABQBmSpAXFFgJRr1TUAdMKy0AUGIDGAezbAoAW0RJO8ZGigs2vVPyHDWpcTLlQU6Rnk5IArgoBGEAE47+eKbNLzyFq1C9OyADmrlDuJl4CSABMADT+0bQaSsiM1EjxRtwSMYwAjNmk0YwA5Hkl2WIA9FVQAALApAC0+JCSwC1OTtJOYrllFdW1Dc2tEO2d3b1F+dxAA)

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, I updated my question with little more details: there is also a mapper function